# Start Service from SystemService

Tags: android, android-service, android-source

How do I start a `Service` (resident in `/packages` folder) from a `SystemService` integrated into the system by the `SystemServer`?

Otherwise starting an `Activity` from a `SystemService` would be perfect. Is that possible, too?

I'm aware that this is against the usability and so on but, but it's an research object.

Comment: What exact SystemService do you mean?

Comment: I wrote my own remote Service and added it as SystemService

Answer (score 0):

To start a service from SystemService you need to register it in `frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java` in ServerThread. Look there for an example.